# ElasticSearch unable to configure multiple data directories

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration

I have installed latest version of elasticsearch through yum on CentOS. 
I have mounted two different disks which I want to configure as data directories.
When I modify `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` and add the parameter `path.data: /data_dir1,/data_dir2` the service fails to start with the following error:

`elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-09-09 16:57:57 PDT; 348ms ago
Docs: http://www.elastic.co
Process: 6586 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet -Edefault.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Edefault.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Edefault.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 6583 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 6586 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

It fails even if I use a single data directory instead of comma separated values.

I also tried modifying `/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service` and removed the line `-Edefault.path.data=${DATA_DIR}` but no luck.

If I comment out `path.data:` in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` file, the service starts fine.
Please help.

Comment: Can you check whether `elasticsearch` user has proper permissions(r&w) on data directories?

Comment: I installed elasticsearch and doing everything as root, I did not configure any separate user accounts for elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `elasticsearch` user and groups set for these directories.

You can do this with `chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch $datadir`.

Comment: That fixed it!!